# How to center the core plot graph on the view controller?

Tags: iphone

I am working on core-plot. I want to make the graph which drawn in the screen need to be centered.  when the application get loaded its showing from the bottom the graph.  I want to make the entire view visible from center has shown in below figure.

@Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

// Just set the xRange and YRange with initial offset:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

/* Range which is visible on screen */

plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(offset) 
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(X_LENGTH)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(offset_Y) 
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(Y_LENGTH)];


/* Total Range which is visible on screen and can be scrolled up to */

CPTPlotRange *globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(Y_LENGTH)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = globalYRange;

CPTPlotRange *globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xRange)];
plotSpace.globalXRange = globalXRange;
```

/* To constraint X and Y axis */

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:55.0];
axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```